# What OSX application positioner is this?

Tags: macos

You can see it used [here at 2:53](http://youtu.be/f7AU2Ozu8eo?t=2m53s). The program appears to be a quick way to switch between and/or reposition OSX applications. Anybody have any idea what program this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/).

> It allows you to quickly and efficiently “divvy up” your screen into exact portions.

[image: divvy screenshot]